# Any good ruby/rails twitter accounts to follow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm looking for good ruby/rails oriented twitter accounts to follow. Interesting in news/events in life of ruby/rails community.

Comment: Following: http://twitter.com/rails, http://twitter.com/ruby_news

Comment: http://www.yatishmehta.in/20-twitter-handles-to-follow-for-ruby-on-rails-developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yehuda Katz [@wycats](http://twitter.com/wycats) is a great one to follow.

A great way to search is to search for people's lists.. look at someone like @dhh and see what lists he's in and then look from there.

Here's my [Rails List](http://twitter.com/mental_thinking/rails)

Answer (score 0):

http://twitter.com/dhh

Comment: why does everyone have to kiss that guy's a**, that arrogant bastard

Answer (score 0):

I watch a twitter search stream of

> "ruby on rails" OR #rails

http://twitter.com/sof_ruby isn't Rails oriented but some questions (such as this one) do come up.